# Error 500 al mover una imagen a public/storage Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web

Hola amigos el problema que tengo es que al ejecutar este código:

```
    $image = $request->file('picture');
    $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->move(public_path('storage/courses'),$imageName);
```

me esta generando un error 500, y para ser mas especifico lo que los genera el la linea 3, esto solo pasa en el servidor, ya que de manera local todo funciona correctamente. Me podrian ayudar con esto, gracias.

Este me da en en log:
error

```
log
[22:18:00] LOG.error: Unable to write in the "/var/www/sibech-elearning/public/storage/courses" directory {"userId":1,"exception":{}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente tiene un tema de permisos en el servidor.

Primero, la carpeta 'courses' ya existe?

Una opción es asignar la propiedad de 'courses' al usuario del servidor, que generalmente es 'www-data' en apache.

La otra opción, menos segura y que seguramente será refutada aquí pero que te la dejo porque me ha permitido avanzar en ocasiones en que Laravel no dejaba grabar contenido es /storage es asignar permisos 777 al directorio en cuestión:

```
chomd 777 storage/courses
```

Comment: Si logre arreglarlo, el problema solo era que faltaba permisos a la carpeta storage/courses